# Expected Value of a time series model

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

Consider a time series that is well described by the model
$$
X_t = 2 + 0.6 X_{t-1} + 0.2X_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t,
$$
where $\varepsilon_t\sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma_\varepsilon^2)$ is a white noice process. Then $E[X_t] = 10$.

My question is: why is the expected value of the time series $10$?
What calculations do I need to compute?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, could you format this with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Does the Image help? I'm sorry but I have no idea how to use mathjax

Comment: @Nuno do you like the changes I made to your question?

Comment: @therkel, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should convince yourself that to solve this, you need to assume that the time series process given by the representation you have is stationary. You can check whether such assumption makes sense.

Now, if the time series is stationary, then the expectation does not change over time, i.e. $E[X_t] = E[X_{t-k}]$ for all $k$.

Taking the expectation on both sides of your equation then gives

$$
E[X_t] = 2+ 0.6\, \overbrace{E[X_t]}^{ = E[X_{t-1}]}\, + 0.2\,\overbrace{E[X_t]}^{ = E[X_{t-2}]}\, + \overbrace{\,0\,}^{ = E[\varepsilon_t]}
$$
which is an equation you can probably easy solve.

Comment: "First you should convince yourself that the time series process given by the representation you have is stationary (it is)." The phrase is a little odd since there are processes $(X_t)$ which satisfy this recursion and are not stationary. Perhaps replace this by "First you should convince yourself that to solve this, one should assume that the time series process given by the representation you have is stationary" or something similar.

Comment: @Did thank you for the correction. I guess my formulation has arisen from a wrong understanding of what it means for a time series to be have a stationary representation.